# Remove empty list from list of list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket, removeall, empty-list

I have a list of list and I want to remove all the empty list from it.

My list is `(("O") ("O") ())`.

If I do

```
(remove '() '(("O") ("O") ()))
```

I get the right output `(("O") ("O"))`

but with `remove*` (which from the documentation remove all the occurence) I get the same input list, i.e.:

```
(remove* '() '(("O") ("O") ()))
```

gives me back

```
(("O") ("O") ())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it works with  `(filter (lambda (element) (not (empty? element))) list))) ` but still don't know what was wrong with the  `remove* `

Comment: I see that you've got this answered, but since "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself," could you also show an example of `remove*` that demonstrates the unexpected result?

Comment: Not sure I have understood what you mean @JoshuaTaylor but I have edited the question. Is it correct now? (thanks anyway for the commnet)

Comment: It was correct before, but now it has more context and shows what the unexpected output was.  I hope that this might make it easier for _future_ users to find the question and its answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, `remove*` doesn't exist in Scheme (R5RS, R6RS, R7RS). `remove` does exist in R6RS and does what you want:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))
(remove '() '(() (1) (2) () ())) ;==> ((1) (2))
```

In the scheme dialect Racket you have both `remove` and `remove*`and it seems you are using racket since it does work in the way you are describing.  `remove*` takes a list of items to remove. Thus `(remove '() lst)` in `#!R6RS` is the same as `(remove* '(()) lst)` in `#!racket`. `remove*` seems to be made to remove all of the matching elements:

```
(remove* '(() (2)) '(() (1) (2) () ())) ; ==> ((1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and yes indeed I am using DrRacket (Pretty Big)